# Using css code in Intel xdk with bootstrap framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I use css style in Intel xdk with bootstrap framework but css code isn't work why?

Comment: Please be clearer . That mistake you ? As you 're getting ? For bootstrapping online url or file?

Comment: I make a col and then I want to style this col by css code .{border-radius:5px;}I write it in a class then add it to col but this code isn't working

Comment: It lets you make columns and do not run a border-radius?well you put calls to CSS and JS from the main theme? @user6015571

Comment: Yea it doesn't run border radius.yes in main theme

Answer (score 0):

Paint the column color or try a bootstrap css "one button for example" . It may be that border-radius does not detect the Intel XDK @user6015571